# Date/Time, scheduled filters and Data Refresh to current date in power bi

Tags: python, powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI5AX.png)

I want the date when I press refresh and the date filter will always be the current date.

ex. date in picture is 9/20/2023 and when I press refresh data I want the date in filter to be 10/03/2023(Today)